# Call variables in string.xml

Tags: java, android, xml, eclipse, string

Please see my previous question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21026786/show-toast-widget-underneath-a-view) for the full code.

In case I want to internationalize my app, I need to create string objects for some statements in my project. The one bothering me most is this code block.

```
    ...
    else
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, 
            "Good job! The answer was " + comp + ".\n" +
            "You made " + guesses + " guesses.\n" +
            "Restart the app to try again.", 
            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
};
```

The relative part to this in the strings.xml looks like:

```
<string name="correct">Good job! The answer was + comp\n
               You made + guesses + guesses.\n
               Restart the app to try again.</string>
```

I want the comp and guesses variables to show their respective values, **but I don't know how.**

I plan to do this to the code block

```
    ...
    else
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, 
            R.string.correct, 
            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
};
```

Thank you.

Comment: This has been answered elsewhere. For e.g. see this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/3656409/415412

Comment: Thanks Suchintya.  Didn't realize that, but it's an awesome resource.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

In your xml file string.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
     <string name="correct">Good job! The answer was %1$s\n
               You made %2$s guesses.\n
               Restart the app to try again.</string>
</resources>
```

If you want to put an other value in the text, you increment %2$s -> %3$s , etc ...

Then you can use it like in java like that :

```
Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, getString(R.string.correct, comp, guesses), 
            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

Comment: This is definitely the best way to handle this, and I did not know about *that* `getString` method - I've been using `String.format(Locale, String, Object...)`. Nice!

Answer (score 1):

Store a format string in the resource and use [String.format](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/String.html#format%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object...%29) to replace the **comp** and **guesses** placeholders.  Use the appropriate places holders for each and include the variables as arguments to format().  You can find details of what placeholders to use under the [Formatter class](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Formatter.html).

The resource would then be something like:

```
<string name="correct">Good job! The answer was %s \n
           You made %d guesses.\n
           Restart the app to try again.</string>
```

And the code would be:

```
...
else
    String correctFormat = getString(R.string.correct);
    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, 
        String.format(correctFormat, comp, guesses),
        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

};

Answer (score 0):

you would use

```
context.getResources().getString(r.id.correct);
```

then create a values folder for each language you want

Answer (score 0):

As @Andros said,

In your string.xml

```
<string name="correct">Good job! The answer was %1$s\n
           You made %2$s guesses.\n
           Restart the app to try again.</string>
```

In your code,

```
Resources res = getResources();
Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, String.format(res.getString(R.string.correct),comp, guesses),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

Comment: You don't need to get the Resource because getString() is directly available from a context. And you dont have to use String.format() because with getString(int, Object ...), you can do it directly.

Comment: Yeah, you are right. It's just a generalized answer. It works even for, say nested classes too.

Answer (score 0):

In string.xml

```
<string name="correct" formatted="false">Good job! The answer was %s\n
               You made %s guesses.\n
               Restart the app to try again.</string>
```

In java :

```
Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,String.format(context.getString(R.string.correct),comp,guesses), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```