# How to anchor a toast to a view, without overlapping them?

Tags: android, toast

### Background

Popups can be anchored to views, but the Toast is missing this API.

What I'd like to know, is how to correctly position a toast near a view (suppose prefer to put below if on upper half of screen, and above if on bottom half), so that they won't overlap each other, no matter the position&size of the view (unless really impossible because the view takes too much space, of course).

### The problem

I'm aware there are various questions to this question, but all set the toast to be shown below the view, or manually set its position, without regard to the size of both of them.

### What I've found

Currently I've found the next solutions:

- [**here**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13683701/878126), it doesn't take the size of the toast into consideration
- [**here**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21026866/878126), it lets you set the position of the toast manually, so they can still overlap each other.

It could be, however, that the toast that appears from long clicking an action item is anchored to the action item's view, but I didn't find out how it works there.

I've also tried many libraries from [**Android-Arsenal website**](https://android-arsenal.com/tag/104), but all of them are either for styling the toasts, or make things that aren't toasts and sometimes don't even work well.

### The question

Is there a generic way to use the same method used for Popups, on Toasts, so that it will be anchored to a view, without overlapping it?

Comment: May I ask why toast?

Comment: @Blackbelt Well, I want to have a similar behavior as the one of action items, so that people who don't understand the meaning of the icon could long click it and see.

Answer (score 1):

You can set gravity for Toast in android like this

```
Toast toast = Toast.makeText(test.this,"bbb", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
toast.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0);
toast.show();
```

and rather play around giving int values. like

```
toast.setGravity(5,6,5);
```

and also try other values..

Another way is, you should create a custom toast like view under a layout

check this library

https://github.com/sephiroth74/android-target-tooltip

Comment: I want to put it near the given view, without overlapping it.

Comment: then create a custom toast view , that look like toast

Comment: I don't need a custom view. I want the native look&feel of a normal toast. and the library that you've provided isn't of a toast. Plus, it can crash easily by rotating the screen while it shows a message.

Comment: you have to create native look&feel toast , no other way and if it crashes on rotate then you have to handle that also , because that library will provide only the interface

Comment: Yes, so as I wrote, no reason to use this library.